# Overfitting and ROC curves

Tags: classification, roc, auc

Is it possible to understand if a classifier is overfitted just by looking at its ROC curve? 
I see that if its AUC it's too high (example 98%) is likely to be overfitted, but it can also mean that the classifier is just really good. Is there a way to tell these two cases apart?

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, it is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Long answer: to estimate overfitting you need to assess your model on an independent dataset. Or use cross-validation, or something similar.